# How to avoid showing the filename when using graphicx?

Tags: graphics

I am writing a LaTeX document with the `apacite` and `graphicx` package. The issue is when I include an image either using `figure` with an enclosed `\includegraphics` or `\includegraphics` by itself it shows the image with the file name to the side.

For example:

```
            --------------
            |             |
            |    BOX 1    |  
            ---------------
Error1.jpg
```

I do not want it to write Error1.jpg. Would show the image but it seems I do not have enough rep.

This is an example tex file to show the error (with Windows XP, using Miktex 2.8).

```
\documentclass[man]{apa}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document} 

\includegraphics{Example Error1.jpg}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\includegraphics{Example Error1.jpg}
\caption{This is the caption of the figure.}
\label{fig:fig2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Old post, but you can do the following.

```
\includegraphics{"Example Error1".jpg}
```

Comment: This should *definitely* be the chosen answer.

Comment: I used the answer given by Claudio Fiandrino of simply adding "" around the file name for example, `\includegraphics{"Example Error1".jpg}`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I'm using a filename with spaces in a for loop (ie `bla 001.png`, `bla 002.png`, `bla 003.png`, etc)

Answer (score 31):

You should also avoid other special characters like underscores in the complete path and the name of the file. But you can use the [grffile](http://ctan.org/pkg/grffile) package for extended file processing. For this case, just add the following line:

```
\usepackage{grffile}
```

Comment: The `grffile` is recommended. Another solution for spaces is enclosing the file name between `"`: `\includegraphics{"Example Error1"}`, but this may break if `babel` is used.

Comment: Simply `\usepackage{grffile}` is sufficient to fix this.  Thanks!

Comment: FYI, when I used grffile for my dissertation to include many small PDF figures it took an order of magnitude longer to compile.

Comment: This works even in combination with `babel` and `beamer`!

Comment: This package works with XeTex Like a charm!!!! It makes the graphics Inclusion painless.

Comment: I use underscore instead of space to make the file name a single string and it solves the problem.

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer while writing this since I wrote `ExampleError1.jpg` when doing the example image. The problem is that `graphicx` doesn't seem to like the spaces in the file name and it assumes it should write it. I tried writing `Example\ Error1.jpg` but it didn't like it either. The solution I propose is that write these filenames without spaces.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is simple. No need to change your existing file names or use a different package.

Do 2 things:

1. Use {} to encircle your file name so that `\includegraphics` does not see the dots and spaces in your path;
2. Use "" inside the {} so that the filename is not displayed in your pdf printout.

Example:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{{"../Current folder/1.This file"}.png}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

(For Windows users,) please note that **the slashes all need to be forward slashes**.

Comment: Using braces is quite dangerous, because it depends, how the file name is internally parsed. A change and the curly braces will become part of the file name.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you add the package `graphics`, you might not avoid the problem if the document class is declared as `draft`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, draft]{report}
```

It is worth to remove the `draft` in the document class so the images will be displayed.

Comment: A global option `draft` can be overruled by a local package option `final` (`\usepackage[final]{graphicx}`).