# How to rid of automatic .pdf label from \includegraphics?

Tags: tables, graphics, pdf, captions, labels

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to avoid showing the filename when using graphicx?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4129/how-to-avoid-showing-the-filename-when-using-graphicx)

So I'm using the `\includegraphics` command to put a PDF image of a table into my LaTeX file here, but this pesky `"filename".pdf` caption comes up with the image and I can't figure out how to get rid of it. Here's my code:

```
\addtolength{\voffset}{80pt}
\oddsidemargin=1cm

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\caption{Short GRB sample data.}
\includegraphics[trim = 10mm 30mm 8mm 30mm, clip,,width=10in]{Short GRB data table3.pdf}

(References included on next page).

\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\newpage
```

I would post an image if I could, but apparently I can't as a new poster. Help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please, have a look at the linked question; this should solve your problem, which basically is in the spaces in the file name.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wish to say, in your output file, the image file name appears at the top of it. Isn't it?

Then, I was in the same problem... It's very easy to solve.
Use

```
\includegraphics[trim = 10mm 30mm 8mm 30mm, clip,,
   width=10in]{ShortGRBdatatable3.pdf}
```

In your image file name, do not use any space. If you need, use "_". If you have any space at the name of the image file, it will appear at the top of your image on output. So rename your image file and try it. Hope it will solve your problem.