# How do I insert pdf image into LaTeX without showing the file location?

Tags: graphics

This is the code I'm using and the image comes up but with the file location next to it

```
\begin{figure}      
    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{C:/Users/Lauren/Google Drive/japan_all_6.pdf}}
    \caption{Plotted data showing a quadractic trend for Japan over $6.0$ $1900-1980$}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: (And [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx))

Answer (score 1):

The reason the file path shows is your use of special characters in the file name. See this
[question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4129/how-to-avoid-showing-the-filename-when-using-graphicx). A straight forward fix is to use the `\usepackage{grffile}` package that helps to deal with those kind of characters.