# How to remove the default title in minipage?

Tags: minipage

I am currently using overleaf online generating side by side plots.

This is my code:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.33\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{FC SVM for Ctl-AD.png}
\caption{fig1}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.33\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{FC SVM for Ctl-PD.png}
\caption{fig2}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.33\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{FC SVM for Ctl-ADPD.png}
\caption{fig3}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

It proves that everything is perfect except for the three default titles(like: "FC SVM for Ctl-AD.png") on each of the three subplots.

This is the effect of minipage.

[image]

Are there any ways to remove the three titles?

Comment: Don't use spaces in file names.

Comment: Minipages does not have titles.

Comment: Hi, as the other comments indicate, minipages do not have any default title, what you're seeing is a result of having spaces in the filenames of the images, just like in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4129/how-to-avoid-showing-the-filename-when-using-graphicx See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8422. This looks like a fairly clear duplicate, so I'm going to vote to close. (Nothing wrong with your question, that's just the usual method. If your problem hasn't been solved, please edit your question saying what you've tried.)