# How to remove/ hide the name of the image in the LaTeX file?

Tags: includegraphics

In my LaTeX file, the name of the image appeared. May I know how can I remove it?
Thank you very much.[image]

My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}


%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}






%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}



%%%
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics{Albert Einstein.jpg}
\caption{Relationship between graphs}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Use a file name without spaces. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4129/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8422/35864.

Comment: Please consider pasting your code as copyable text directly into the question. Please don't add code only as a picture. Code in pictures is not only a nuisance because copy-and-paste does not work and it is not indexed by search engines, it is also a huge accessibility issue for people with screen readers.

Comment: unrelated but don't use `[h]`, latex usually warns about that and changes it to `[ht]` but `[htp]` is better